# "Last login:" - printing "days" when login time is more than one day ago

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, authentication

Our CodeIgniter-based website has a section showing the last time a user logged in (using days if necessary and hrs, min, sec). I'm trying to make it print "day" when the result is 1 day and "days" when it is over 1 day. At the moment 1 day shows as `1 day` but 2 days (and above) shows as `2 day 2 days`. Can you see what I've done wrong here and modify the code?

`$dDf` = day

`$hDf` = hour

`$mDf` = minute

`$sDf` = second

```
<?php
    if ($dDf < 1) {
        if ($hDf > 0) {
            if ($mDf < 0) {
                $mDf = 60 + $mDf;
                $hDf = $hDf - 1;
                echo $mDf . ' min';
            } else {
                echo $hDf . ' hr ' . $mDf . ' min';
            }
        } else {
            if ($mDf > 0) {
                echo $mDf . ' min ' . $sDf . ' sec';
            } else {
                echo $sDf . ' sec';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo $dDf . ' days ';

        if ($dDf > 1) {
            if ($hDf > 0) {
                if ($mDf < 0) {
                    $mDf = 60 + $mDf;
                    $hDf = $hDf - 1;
                    echo $mDf . ' min';
                } else {
                    echo $hDf . ' hr ' . $mDf . ' min';
                }
            } else {
                if ($mDf > 0) {
                    echo $mDf . ' min ' . $sDf . ' sec';
                } else {
                    echo $sDf . ' sec';
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo $dDf . ' day ';

            if ($hDf > 0) {
                if ($mDf < 0) {
                    $mDf = 60 + $mDf;
                    $hDf = $hDf - 1;
                    echo $mDf . ' min';
                } else {
                    echo $hDf . ' hr ' . $mDf . ' min';
                }
            } else {
                if ($mDf > 0) {
                    echo $mDf . ' min ' . $sDf . ' sec';
                } else {
                    echo $sDf . ' sec';
                }
            }
        }


    }
?>
```

Comment: Wow, who's up for decoding obscure variables? Just a tip, verbosity in variable names can go a long way.

Comment: I'm guessing `$mDf` is minutes etc? -_-

Comment: You're right guys - I should have written the variable titles, sorry about that. `$dDf` = day (that's the only relevant one for this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use the built-in `timespan()` function for this?

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('date');
echo timespan($last_logged_in_timestamp);
```

Comment: The main reason is our site is actually in Czech and the `timespan` results are English, but this can probably be altered using MySQL date variables. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: The function uses the Language class, so you should be able to set `date_year`, `date_month`, `date_weeks`, etc. (and their plural equivalents) in a language file.  I've never needed to do it, but it doesn't look too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to write something, but a very simple google search that lasted no more than 60 seconds came up with **[THIS](http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/making-time-periods-readable/)**, so there you have it. The code inside:

```
/**
 * A function for making time periods readable
 *
 * @author      Aidan Lister <aidan@php.net>
 * @version     2.0.1
 * @link        http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/making-time-periods-readable/
 * @param       int     number of seconds elapsed
 * @param       string  which time periods to display
 * @param       bool    whether to show zero time periods
 */
function time_duration($seconds, $use = null, $zeros = false)
{
    // Define time periods
    $periods = array (
        'years'     => 31556926,
        'Months'    => 2629743,
        'weeks'     => 604800,
        'days'      => 86400,
        'hours'     => 3600,
        'minutes'   => 60,
        'seconds'   => 1
        );

    // Break into periods
    $seconds = (float) $seconds;
    $segments = array();
    foreach ($periods as $period => $value) {
        if ($use && strpos($use, $period[0]) === false) {
            continue;
        }
        $count = floor($seconds / $value);
        if ($count == 0 && !$zeros) {
            continue;
        }
        $segments[strtolower($period)] = $count;
        $seconds = $seconds % $value;
    }

    // Build the string
    $string = array();
    foreach ($segments as $key => $value) {
        $segment_name = substr($key, 0, -1);
        $segment = $value . ' ' . $segment_name;
        if ($value != 1) {
            $segment .= 's';
        }
        $string[] = $segment;
    }

    return implode(', ', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an [old example](https://github.com/jwandborg/php-webtools/blob/master/tools.class.php#L80) in my code library. It should give you an idea of how to do it.

```
function time_readable($duration) {
    $days = floor($duration/86400);
    $hrs = floor(($duration - $days * 86400) / 3600);
    $min = floor(($duration - $days * 86400 - $hrs * 3600) / 60);
    $s = $duration - $days * 86400 - $hrs * 3600 - $min * 60;

    $return = ($days > 0) ? $days . ' d ' : '';
    $return .= ($days > 0 || $hrs > 0) ? $hrs . ' hours ' : '';
    $return .= ($days > 0 || $hrs > 0 || $min > 0) ? $min . ' min ' : '';
    $return .= ($days > 0 || $hrs > 0 || $min > 0) ? $s . ' s ' : '';

    return $return;
}
```